# What is the implication of suicide for home buying among Jewish people?

Tags: transactions, real-estate, home-house, suicide

We have seen a property in an prominently Jewish area. It is owned by a Jewish lady whose husband committed suicide almost 8 years ago by overdosing with sleeping pills. We are not Jewish and the house looks good in terms of location. But if we will be reselling it after some years, will this information affect Jewish people's decision on whether to buy it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you think this might affect Jews' decision to buy the house?

Comment: Generally, though suicide is not technically permitted in Judaism, we assume that the person was not in his or her right mind when committing suicide, thereby excusing the act.

Comment: For some buyers it changes their opinions. For instance, I talked to a person of Chinese origin (the largest group of buyers in Toronto, where I live) and it is enough to influence his decision. Since it is in Jewish area- most likely next buyer will be of Jewish origin.

Comment: What I meant is, what makes you think that this will have a particular effect on the person <i>because</i> he is Jewish?

Comment: @Daniel, fyi: Underscore before and after text gets you italics.

Comment: @SethJ, thanks! I've been trying to figure out how to get italics in the comments for a while now.

Comment: @Daniel Because the OP doesn't know much about Jews except that they have a lot of particular rules.

Comment: Yes, my knowledge of Judaism is limited as Double AA mentioned. Some cultures/ religions believe in energy/ spirits and consider incidents similar to these as ominous.

Answer (score 5):

There are Jewish communities which have the custom that if a tragedy happened in a home, the current owners will move out.

This is based on the Rabbinic expression "*one who changes his location changes his luck*".

However, there is no reason for somebody else not to move into such a home. In Jerusalem - and other predominantly Jewish areas - such homes are occasionally put up for sale and do not stay long on the market.

Even if somebody would have a custom not to move into such a home, if it were owned by somebody else since the tragedy then it would be considered "safe", as they are not buying it from anybody related to the tragedy.

That said, you will always find people who are very superstitious and will refuse to even walk near such a home. This has no basis in Judaism, as far as I know.

Comment: There seems to be a minhag with a newly built house that goyim should first live there.

Comment: @preferred - that's amazing, especially when considering that there's an issue letting non-Jews live in a Jewish neighbourhood; as we see when learning about Eiruv-Chatzeirot. (I also wonder how they kept that Minhag in the ghettos...)